# What is the correct moduli space of inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Two possible candidates for the moduli space of inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$ come to mind:

1. the space $S_n$ of positive-definite symmetric real $n\times n$ matrices; or,
2. the classifying space $BO(n)$.

Why 1: the points of $S_n$ are in clear bijection with inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Why 2: due to the groupoid equivalence $[X,BO(n)] \simeq (\text{rank-$n$ real v.b.'s on $X$ with bundle metric})$,
applying $X = \mathrm{pt}$,
we see that the groupoid of rank-$n$ real v.b.'s equipped with bundle metric over $\mathrm{pt}$ (which should correspond to inner products on a vector space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$) is equivalent to the fundamental groupoid of $BO(n)$; in particular inner products on a real dimension-$n$ vector space correspond to points of $BO(n)$.

---

Is $BO(n)$ "larger" because it also carries information about inner products on all possible dimension-$n$ vector spaces, instead of just $\mathbb{R}^n$?

What would be the appropriate formal context in which to distinguish these two "types" of moduli spaces?

Apologies if my reasoning is informal and/or mistaken; I have little familiarity with the concept of moduli space.

Comment: Classification… at what granularity? The answer depends.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you! Here by "granularity" do you mean in the sense of "coarse" vs "fine" moduli spaces?

Comment: Not specifically. My point is the same as Qiaochu's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space of positive-definite symmetric real $n \times n$ matrices is the moduli space of inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$, in a very concrete sense. $BO(n)$ is, in a less concrete (homotopical) sense, the moduli space of inner products on *$n$-dimensional real vector spaces*; note the difference here (we haven't chosen a basis, or equivalently, we haven't chosen an isomorphism of such a vector space with $\mathbb{R}^n$).

This is in fact what you've written, so just take the time to notice that these are not the same thing.